# Extract actual type from object based on type with optional properties

Tags: typescript

Assuming some flexable types with several optional fields:

```js
type PushTypes = "start" | "finish" 
type PullTypes = "start" | "stop"

interface Notes {
  push: Partial<Record<PushTypes, boolean>>;
  pull?: Partial<Record<PullTypes, boolean>>;
}
```

and concrete objects created within those types

```js
const DefaultServerNotes: Notes = {
  push: {
    start: true,
    finish: true,
  },
};

const DefaultClientNotes: Notes = {
  push: { finish: true },
  pull: { stop: true },
};
```

How do I extract the types from the 'concrete' objects so that I end up with the following types?

```js
// type ServerNotes = typeof DefaultServerNotes (nope)
type ServerNotes = {
    push: {
        start: boolean;
        finish: boolean;
    }
};

// type ClientNotes = typeof DefaultClientNotes 
type ClientNotes = {
    push: { finish: boolean },
    pull: { stop: boolean }
}
```

I've combed through the corpus of the usual suspects and come up empty. I suspect my queries are not up to par, leaving me without a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [annotate a variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as being of type `Notes` as you've defined it:

```
const DefaultServerNotes: Notes = {...}; // too late!
```

then you cannot extract the type from the concrete objects.  Because `Notes` is not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type (more on this below), a value of type `Notes` is, and will always be, a value of type `Notes`.  Any extra information the compiler had about the value assigned to the variable has been thrown away, and it's too late to get it back.  Its type has been *widened* to `Notes`, whereas you want the type to stay *narrow*.

---

One simple way to proceed here is to just *not* annotate those variables:

```
const DefaultServerNotes = {
    push: {
        start: true,
        finish: true,
    },
};

type ServerNotes = typeof DefaultServerNotes
/* type ServerNotes = {
    push: {
        start: boolean;
        finish: boolean;
    };
} */
```

Because TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), the compiler will be happy to accept those non-annotated variables wherever a `Notes` value is needed:

```
function needNotes(notes: Notes) {
    console.log(notes.pull?.start);
}
needNotes(DefaultClientNotes); // okay
needNotes(DefaultServerNotes); // okay
```

and any error in your variable's definition will be caught there:

```
const badNotes = { push: { stop: true } }
needNotes(badNotes); // error!
// Types of property 'push' are incompatible.
```

---

If you really want errors to appear right where you assign the variable, you can use a helper function instead of an annotation:

```
const asNotes = <T extends Notes>(n: T) => n;
```

The `asNotes()` function only accepts an input assignable to `Notes`:

```
const oops = asNotes({
    push: {
        stop: true // error!
    }
})
```

but does not widen its type to `Notes`:

```
const okay = asNotes({
    push: {
        start: true,
        finish: true,
    },
});

type Okay = typeof okay
/* type Okay = {
  push: {
      start: true;
      finish: true;
  };
} */

needNotes(okay); // okay
```

---

Now, if `Notes` were a union type, the compiler would be able to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow the apparent type of your variables to just some subset of the union upon the assignment of the variable.  This would behave much like you want.

Unfortunately, you'd have to make `Notes` a type alias instead of an interface, and spell out or compute every possible type you'd like to be able to extract.  Instead of attempting to do this in general, I'm going to use just the two subtypes you mention explicitly:

```
type ServerNotes = {
    push: {
        start: boolean;
        finish: boolean;
    }
};

type ClientNotes = {
    push: { finish: boolean },
    pull: { stop: boolean }
}

type Notes = ServerNotes | ClientNotes;
```

Once you do this, the narrowing happens for free:

```
const DefaultServerNotes: Notes = {
    push: {
        start: true,
        finish: true,
    },
};
type SN = typeof DefaultServerNotes;
/* type SN = {
  push: {
    start: boolean;
    finish: boolean;
  };
} */
```

But I probably wouldn't recommend this method here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgrgZwBYBVwQVAvFARA4AQwCdhcoAfPAMwEsA7W5XAKFEljgBsu1JMc+IqXJUhAezCsW9QgFsMYQgGNoAOXEBBevXFFg0AN4sWUM1AYHi1Fer0Yox886hhESAFywSwWoS4APABKEMrixAAmAfDIfBgANFAARuLiXBCE9AB8WQDcpi5mbjwA-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-XvR9oAPf8gMTQdnirPCCMPZdBQE0thJRW9NPFYRgEkvF5QDeEcUM5wkXM-s1kNAB5I9zXQCDF2XdkuVs+ywWRUSdPMXtJJDQpjP85Fkx6VM8LXUtnJAX8VJXFhehMWQFAQJRVCgABVRhc1WayeR3EixO9a4fOcPy4zaWVEwVWFA3jKqHi1TiiR5CdCp87yYSuKEg0yJMzK0nh0QkirVRfcy8MNQqCo9Kg2odPouI+OkGVmJkWUrD1PPDErqt8vSDL2swgpuUy5MM0KXRJNQHMgCCt2mNb+QwENnUNKYbu24qoR88rerVRMTv+gKkwHcKlNPQiHvmisoHaxNOpOhF+oRiM7xjB9TqfCznhDQ0fk+q77pWm1-jtFlXrc1rCa9bzAdqnr6oB8yQ1RSNdNjYGmq1cHuiAA)

Comment: Thanks. This is absolute gold. The `asNotes` is my favorite but I really appreciate the in-depth answer which provided me with the extra insight I needed.